# determine the PC of code gadgets in PLT section of ELF file

Tags: elf, symbols, plt

I am trying to parse an ELF file using custom code. With reference to the image below (output displayed is from `objdump`), I need to get the address of code gadget starting at , for example 401030 for the symbol printf@plt in the .plt section  , so for example when I get `st_value` for `ELF64_Sym` symbol `printf@plt`, it gives me a value of 0, and `st_size` is also 0. The `r_offset` field from `ELF64_Rela` also gives me the address in `GOT` table `404018`, and not `401030`. I was wondering how do I get this PC of `401030`?

[image]